# Is it "you have better places to be at" or "you have better places to be"?

Tags: prepositions

A suggestion in my class textbook, International Management: Strategic Opportunities & Cultural Challenges, that says,

> "Do not be in a rush, as it is an attack on the face of others. To
>   Asians, your sense of urgency says that they are not important enough
>   to spend time with and that you have better places to be."

Shouldn't it say "better places to be **at**"?

You drive a car. That's why you have better cars to drive.

But,

You dream about a car. That's why you have better cars to dream about.

Shouldn't the same logic hold true for the original sentence?

Answer (score 3):

"Better places to **be**" is correct here.

When you say "dream about", the "about" is necessary because "better cars to dream" would be incomplete. Not so with "better places to be".

I don't think "better places to be **at**" would be totally wrong here, but I feel that "better places to **be**" is far superior.

This is just based on convention. It's the more common way to say it.

Here's another example of usage:

> There you are, assailed by turbo-charged butterflies and baying,
>   beseeching crowds, by managerial demands and collective
>   responsibility, trying like buggery just to keep on keeping on. To do
>   what you've learned to do without thinking, to perform as you do when
>   dogs outnumber spectators and the TV cameras **have better places to be.
>   <sup>[ESPN, 2015](http://www.espncricinfo.com/magazine/content/story/852173.html)</sup>**

Comment: But do we say "There are other places you can (be at/in)"? Don't we include the preposition in that sentence?

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom I prefer to drop *at/in* in that example as well. I would just say *"There are other places you can be."* It may occasionally depend on context.

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom - This is something of a regional or dialect issue too.  Standard usage is to leave off the preposition, but informally I often say things like "Where's the party at?"  This drives my wife nuts, but it's the dialect I grew up speaking.